# When doing network programming, is there a rule of thumb for determining how many threads to use?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

Say I have a list of 1000 unique urls, and I need to open each one, and `assert` that something on the page is there. Doing this sequentially obviously is a poor choice, as most of the time the program will be sitting idle just waiting for a response. So, added in a thread pool where each worker reads from a main `Queue`, and opens a url to do a check. My question is, how big do I make the pool? Is it based on my network bandwidth, or some other metric? Are there any rules of thumb for this, or is it simply trial and error to find an effective size?

This is more of a theoretical question, but here's the basic outline of the code I'm using.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #get the stuff I've already checked
    ID = 0
    already_checked = [i[ID] for i in load_csv('already_checked.csv')]

    #make sure I don't duplicate the effort
    to_check = load_csv('urls_to_check.csv')
    links = [url[:3] for url in to_check if i[ID] not in already_checked]

    in_queue = Queue.Queue()
    out_queue = Queue.Queue()

    threads = []
    for i in range(5):
        t = SubProcessor(in_queue, out_queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    writer = Writer(out_queue)
    writer.setDaemon(True)
    writer.start()

    for link in links:
        in_queue.put(link)
```

Comment: Is it I/O bound or processor bound?  If it's I/O bound, try using the same number of threads as you have processor cores.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought I/O bound stuff could use a higher number of threads than there are cores because the CPU is mostly sitting idle while the actual IO happens (in this case, waiting for a network response). Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I/O bound means you're waiting on I/O.  So unless you have more work for the processors to do while they're spinning the I/O, more threads are pointless.

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/examples

Comment: If the threads are mainly doing network I/O, and no significant disk I/O or number-crunching, you could probably run all 1000 in parallel. If the first 999 URLs are hitting really slow webservers, then at least the 1000th will return quickly. However, I think this is one of those questions to which there's no good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to write some code that runs some tests using the number of threads you specify, and see how many threads produce the best result.   There are too many variables (speed of processor, speed of the buses, thread overhead, number of cores, and the nature of the code itself) for us to hazard a guess.

Comment: DNS lookup and HTTP GET are all very I/O bound.  Parsing the page is not.  Try some different values, yes.

Answer (score 0):

My experience (using .NET, but it should apply to any language) is that DNS resolution ends up being the limiting factor. I found that a maximum of 15 to 20 concurrent requests is all that I could sustain. DNS resolution is typically very fast, but sometimes can take hundreds of milliseconds. Without some custom DNS caching or other way to quickly do the resolution, I found that it averages about 50 ms.

If you can do multi-threaded DNS resolution, 100 or more concurrent requests is certainly possible on modern hardware (a quad-core machine). How your OS handles that many individual threads is another question entirely. But, as you say, those threads are mostly doing nothing but waiting for responses. The other consideration is how much work those threads are doing. If it's just downloading a page and looking for something specific, 100 threads is probably well within the bounds of reason. Provided that "looking" doesn't involve much more than just parsing an HTML page.

Other considerations involve the total number of unique domains you're accessing. If those 1,000 unique URLs are all from the different domains (i.e. 1,000 unique domains), then you have a worst case scenario: every request will require a DNS resolution (a cache miss).

If those 1,000 URLs represent only 100 domains, then you'll only have 100 cache misses. Provided that your machine's DNS cache is reasonable. However, you have another problem: hitting the same server with multiple concurrent requests. Some servers will be very unhappy if you make many (sometimes "many" is defined as "two or more") concurrent requests. Or too many requests over a short period of time. So you might have to write code to prevent multiple or more-than-X concurrent requests to the same server. It can get complicated.

One simple way to prevent the multiple requests problem is to sort the URLs by domain and then ensure that all the URLs from the same domain are handled by the same thread. This is less than ideal from a performance perspective, because you'll often find that one or two domains have many more URLs than the others, and you'll end up with most of the threads ended while those few are plugging away at their very busy domains. You can alleviate these problems by examining your data and assigning the threads' work items accordingly.